# Find the number of local extrema of that function without calculus.

Tags: functions, optimization

I need to find the number of local extrema of that function without derivate or using calculus.

I know that in $x = 1$ and $x = 3$ $f(x) = 0$ ... in which way I can affirm that this function has at least $4$ different local extrema?

$$
f(x) = (x-1)^2(x-3)^4(x+5)^{1/3}
$$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at $g = f^3$ instead will not alter the number (or existence) of extrema since $x \mapsto x^3$ is bijective.
$$ g(x) = (x-1)^6(x-3)^{12}(x+5)$$
From this, since $g$ has degree 19, we know $g(x) \to -\infty$ with $x \to -\infty$ and $g(x) \to \infty$ with $x \to \infty$. We also know it has an odd zero at $x=-5$, followed by an even zero at $x = 1$, and another even zero at $x = 3$.

We pick up an extremum between $x=-5$ and $1$, another at $x=1$ (even zero), another between $x=1$ and $3$, and a final one at $x=3$. That's four extrema. These should coincide with the extrema of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

By using continuity of $f$ and by using its graph we see that between $-5$ and $1$, there is a local extrema because there is a point where the tangent line is horizontal (Rolle's theorem), and between $1$ and $3$ there is another one, and two more at $1$ and $3$ themselves are local min each. Thus at least we can see $4$ already.